# Getting different bytes using Buffered Reader

Tags: java, sockets

I have a problem when I put some bytes into a Client socket `OutputStream` and pass them to Server socket. Using `BufferedReader` I want to read those bytes, but method read() gets characters, so I usually get different values when sending bytes in range `<-128,-1>...` How could I transform those characters to bytes I wanted.

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket s = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 3000);
            is = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();
            int read;
            String str = "";
            while ((read = is.read()) != '\n') {
                str += (char) read;
            }
            System.out.println(str);
            ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
            b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
            b.putInt(430);
            byte[] message = b.array();
            for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(message[i] + " ");
            }
            os.write(message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}



class Robot extends Thread {

    private Socket s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
            while (true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                Robot srv = new Robot();
                srv.s = s;
                srv.start();
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException numberEx) {
            System.out.println("Port of port is not integer");
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            System.out.println("Input connection problem");
        } finally {
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(Robot.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            os = s.getOutputStream();
            os.write("Send me data:\n".getBytes());
            int b;
            while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.println((byte) b + " ");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a Reader to read bytes. Use an InputStream. Reader/Writer are for characters. InputStream/OutputStream are for bytes.

Comment: @JBNizet is right; see [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/strings-characters-bytes-and-character.html) for what is what, since this is a common misconception with Java that "a char is two bytes" -- it really isn't

Comment: Ditto.  Just read your bytes directly from the `InputStream`.  Don't use an `InputStreamReader`, or a `BufferedReader`, or any other class with `Reader` in the name.

Answer (score 0):

The Reader converts the received bytes in characters and use the system property `file.encoding` (you can change it).

If you need characters (Strings) your have to decode and encode it in bytes with a known encoding (e.g. UTF-8). It should (must) be the same on the client and the server.

If you only need bytes (no characters, no Strings) you should only use Streams - no Readers